# WP URL /icons returns 403 forbidden error

Tags: urls, errors

So, this is odd. On WordPress, I'm not allowed to have a page `http://mysite.com/icons`. Apparently that slug doesn't work, and I get an error 403 (forbidden) if I try to go there. This seems silly, as there is no "icons" folder in WP to protect. Any ideas where this is coming from, and how to disable it?

Strangely, if I go to that URL and I haven't made a page, I get the standard 404. But once I've made a page with the slug `icons`, I get a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `/icons` is a default path in the [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Software_Foundation) server.

AFAIK it can’t be changed/overriden in `.htaccess`, because it is defined as *Alias* in the Apache configuration.

See, for example, this question on Stack Overflow: [how to override index of /icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4433631/1591669)